# java split string with scanner not losing delimiters

Tags: java, string, split, delimiter

I got sentences like

```
"Peter Tosh  and Mary Miller  or Michael or Stephan and Andrea Kurnikova"
```

and want to split them either on ***and*** or ***or***

When I am using the code:

```
Scanner fromStr = new Scanner("Peter Tosh  and Mary Miller  or Michael or Stephan and Andrea Kurnikova");
fromStr.useDelimiter(" and | or ");
while (fromStr.hasNext()) {
    String temp = fromStr.next();
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

The result is:

```
Peter Tosh 
Mary Miller 
Michael
Stephan
Andrea Kurnikova
```

But I need the following (not losing the delimiter value):

```
Peter Tosh 
and Mary Miller 
or Michael
or Stephan
and Andrea Kurnikova
```

Please consider that the and/or can differ from sentence to sentence. With other words, it has to be dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Why you are using Scanner and all that loop?* you can just use [`String::split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) which take a regex, and you can use this regex `(?=and|or)` to split :

```
String str = "Peter Tosh  and Mary Miller  or Michael or Stephan and Andrea Kurnikova";
String[] split = str.split("(?=and|or)");
Arrays.asList(split).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Outputs:

```
Peter Tosh  
and Mary Miller  
or Michael 
or Stephan 
and Andrea Kurnikova
```